# Regex not finding specific pair of hexadecimal character

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

python 3.7.4

I've a *.csv that contains numerous instances of the character string

```
High School
```

and numerous instances of the hexadecimal-pair

```
C3 82
```

which I'd like remove.

```
def findem( fn, patt):
  p = re.compile(patt)
  with open( fn, newline = '\n') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
      m = p.search( line)
      if( m):
        print('found {0}'.format(line))

fn_inn = "Contacts_prod.csv"

patt_hs   = "High School"
patt_C382 = r'\\xC3\\x82'

print('trying patt_hs')
findem( fn_inn, patt_hs)    # <------- finds all rows containing High School, great

print('trying patt_C382')
findem( fn_inn, patt_C382)  # <------- doesnt find anything and should
```

As written it should print out which rows contain the  pattern.
With `patt` = `"High School"` everything works as expected.
With `patt` = `r'\xc3\x82'`  nothing gets found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `patt = r"\\xc3\\x82"` if these hex entities are literal. Also, could you please share the exact contents part with the hex chars?

Comment: Try using `re.sub` ro replace matches of the following regular expression with empty strings: `r'(?<!\w)(?:\\xC3 +\\x82|High School)(?!\w)'`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SkrsEq/1/). This causes, for example, `0,bee,High School,\xC3 \x82,ant` to be converted to `0,bee,,,ant`. The negative lookbehind and lookahead cause the string, `0,bee,Thigh School,High Schooler,\xC3 \x82,ant` to be converted to `0,bee,Thigh School,High Schooler,,ant`, even if the case-indifferent flag is set (for `Thigh School`).

Comment: Further to my previous comment, here's a link to a [Python demo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php). Warrior, I think you've confused the question by referring to "hexidecimal pairs". After all, they are merely strings. I believe it would be clearer if you just said you wanted to replace the strings `High School` and `\xC3 \x82` with empty strings.

Comment: refactored code for clarity. Changing to r'\\xC3\\x82'  did not help. Thx so far!

Answer (score 1):

The trick was to 1) quit thinking in terms of finding and displaying each occurrence and remember the goal is to remove all occurrences  and 2) think in terms of binary. Then it became simple, but with some subtleties:

```
def findem( patt):
  p = re.compile(patt)
  with open( fn_out, 'wb') as fp_out:   #binary input
    with open( fn_inn, 'rb') as fp_inn: #binary output
      slurp_i = fp_inn.read()           # slurp_i is of type bytes
      slurp_o = p.sub( b'', slurp_i)    # notice the b'' , very subtle
      fp_out.write( slurp_o)

fn_inn = "Contacts_prod.csv"
fn_out = "Contacts_prod.fixed.dat"

patt = re.compile(b'\xC3\x82')         # notice the b'' instead of r'', very subtle
findem( patt)
```

Thanks to all that responded. All Hail SO!

Still-learning Steve

Comment: I think you can flag your own answer as an answer if you solved it yourself.